# RandomAccessFile throws FileNotFound exception

Tags: filenotfoundexception, randomaccessfile

I am Creating a new File using RandomAccessFile with "rw" mode. but it gives

java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../dir/test.txt (No such file or directory)

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597704/java-io-filenotfoundexception-when-using-randomaccessfile-to-create-file)

This is how i created:

```
File baseDirAsFile = new File("../");

File dirFile = new File(baseDirAsFile, "dir");

File file = new File(dirFile, "test.txt");

RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
```

Note:
   It is not throwing that exception all the time. But can't identify when     and why it is throwing this at some particular time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code should be:

```
String baseDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
String dirFile = baseDirAsFile + File.separator + "dir";
File file = new File(dirFile + File.separator + "test.txt");
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
```

Comment: when i get the path for dirFile it shows the absolutePath there is no difference between both

Comment: Hang on. You're using this to create a file. Why not use `file.createNewFile()` (java.io.File file)

Comment: There isn't supposed to be a difference between the two files. I have never tried using "rw" mode to create the file, and wouldn't. Just use the java.io.File.createNewFile method as above.